# Best way to automate the loading of data daily into google big query from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis, ssis-2016, google-bigquery

Best way to load/copy/insert data from a SQL Server database into a  table in Google Big Query on a daily schedule.

I.E data from a table in a SQL Server database to a table in Google Big Query

I was hoping to use SSIS but there are no native data sources/destinations only 3rd party offerings?

I was thinking of using SSIS to create a CSV file then using Google BQ commandline push the CSV file to big query?

Does anyone have any other better suggestions/methods?

Comment: To better clarify your question, you should either shift to more specific ("How can I use Google Big Query as a destination in a SSIS data flow?", or more general ("How can I load SQL Server data to Google Big Query?"). More specific is probably better, and seems more likely to be what you originally intended.

Comment: Funny how you have arrived at exactly what I have asked?

Comment: No, technically you've asked how to move data between SQL Server and Big Query, mentioning something about SSIS in passing. Solidifying that you're asking about SSIS in particular, or generalizing that you're asking about how to move the data (whether with SSIS or not) may get you past the current "unclear" hold. Note that generalizing may just move your question into the territory of "too broad". If it would be helpful, I'm willing to try to reword the question to make the SSIS requirement specific.

Comment: Yeah it was just confusing the way it was worded. My advice would be to edit the question and reword it the way RDFozz suggested only because you'll get more hits/views on your question and will get help faster. I might be able to help later but it's lunchtime and I'm starving.

Answer (score -1):

See this Q&A at Stack Overflow: [Migrate SQL Server database to BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795598/migrate-sql-server-database-to-bigquery)

SQLCMD is your friend. It dumps the results of a query into a CSV.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any "A" at that link. If you know the answer, you might want to provide a bit more details.